# Inserting values dynamically in a column of a data frame created in a for loop

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I'm wondering how to insert values dynamically in a column of a data frame created in a for loop like this:

```
v = 1:10

for (i in v) {
  dataFrameMio[i] = data.frame(i)
}
```

The above code is wrong; I need to create a dataframe with a single column called for instance "prova", and the value in these column should be the values of i.

Comment: It's not clear what you are actually trying to achieve and if the loop is necessary for your actual use case.

Nevertheless, try this

`v = 1:10
dataFrameMio = data.frame()
for (i in v) {
  dataFrameMio[i, "prova"] = i
}`

Comment: Hello @Quixotic22 perfect, it's what I was looking for. The for loop is needed because I'm using a code where I don't know the number of the values of the column so I've to insert them dynamically with a for loop inside which there is a if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you don't need a loop, would this solve your problem?

```
vectorValues=rnorm(6,10,1)
df=data.frame(prova=vectorValues)
```

If the vectorValues are mandatorily created within a loop, then you could try.
1- First create an empty data-frame with the expected vector size.
2- Then the data-frame for each iteration.

```
#1- Empty data-frame
vectorSize=6
df=data.frame(prova=rep(NA,vectorSize))

#2- Fill the empty data-frame within a loop
for(i in 1:length(vectorValues)){
  randomValue=rnorm(1,10,1)
  df$prova[i]=randomValue
}
```